# Spinner Causes App Crash

Tags: java, android, spinner

I'm new with Stackoverflow and also programming with Android

I've done this code in my AndroidApp:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Spinner spinner;
private LinkedList<Integer> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    this.ageSpinner();


}

private void ageSpinner(){

    list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    spinner = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    for(Integer i=0; i<=4; i++){


        list.add(i);

    }

    ArrayAdapter<Integer> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

}
```

And my logCat throws me a `NullPointerException`.

I've tried to do this code changing the Linkelist to ArrayList, String Array, but my app crash.

Comment: initialize spinner in PlaceHolderFragment onCreateView using `rootView.findViewById`

Comment: Show activity_main file, and tell which line throws this exception.

Comment: does this spinner lie in your fragment you ar loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ageSpinner();
ArrayAdapter<Integer> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}
 private void ageSpinner(){

    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<=4; i++){
        list.add(i);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the Spinner in order for it not to be null.

Using `rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1)` within your `onCreate` method should solve the issue.